Temporal dependencies in time-series
To my knowledge, the algorithms that require stationary input can't capture temporal dependencies. This is inherent due to the fact that the input features must be stationary, thus things like trends, changing market regimes, etc can't be effectively input into the model.
Therefore, when plugging in features to this model, it theoretically shouldn't matter if I were to randomize the time-series before AND THEN calculate these stationary features (like RSI, for example).
Please correct me if I'm wrong, just something that I was thinking about.

Hi: I'm probably not understanding your question but time-series dependence is time based, even for stationary time series, so I wouldn't randomize the time-series. That would remove time dependence or atleast throw it way off.

the algorithms that require stationary input can't capture temporal dependencies. This is not so. ARMA processes are stationary and model time dependence.

Take an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck for example. The process becomes weakly stationary for large times. Yet, it has temporal dependencies: Whenever the spot is far away from its long-term average (mean-reversion level), it will revert back to it. This is a temporal structure.
The situation is different for time-series where the underlying process is a martingale (fair game). Such a series is non-stationary and has no temporal structure in the sense that any information available at a given time $t$ would allow you to predict the next directional move better than a fair coin flip.
Hence it is rather the other way around as you suggest: In a Brownian motion for example that is simplest martingale process, you could shuffle the increments and create another 'realization' of a Brownian motion this way
